# preg_match/regex format needed

Tags: php, regex

I have the below post fields submitted and I am trying to get the value of each of the numbers in the form field for the Quantity. Can someone help me with the regexp? I am trying to get each of the numbers in a variable.

FORMAT

```
Quantity_{Category}_{Product}_{Item}
```

POST FIELDS SUBMITTED

```
[submitted] => 1
[Quantity_12038_16061_24960] => 1
[Quantity_12037_16060_24959] => 2
[btnBuyNow] => Next Step
```

PHP CODE

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_match('/^Quantity_(\d+)$/', $key, $matches)) {
        echo 'Key:' . $key . '<br>';
        echo 'Matches:' . $matches . '<br>';
        echo '<hr>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `preg_match()` [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) for this purpose, and that is a sample of how the code would look like:

```
$subject="Quantity_12038_16061_24960";
$pattern='/Quantity_(\d+)_(\d+)_(\d+)/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);

echo $matches[0]; //12038 {Category}
echo $matches[1]; //16061 {Product}
echo $matches[2]; //24960 {Item}
```

you can see how this regex is performing [here](https://regex101.com/r/cG9wE4/1).

Comment: Thanks it was close but I was able to fix it. Below was the output so I just had to adjust it to pull from 1, 2 & 3 and not 0.

 Array
 (
     [0] => Quantity_12038_16061_24960
     [1] => 12038
     [2] => 16061
     [3] => 24960
 )

Answer (score 1):

As the question is stated, regex is not needed:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {
    if(strpos($key, 'Quantity') === 0) {
        $results = explode('_', $key);
        print_r($results);
    }
}
```

To get rid of the Quantity string for whatever reason just `unset($results[0]);`.